# Don't want to collect luggage in connecting flight

Tags: air-travel, luggage, ams, connecting-flights, jet-airways

I am planning to visit Iceland and don't have any direct flight from Delhi.
As i am a frequent flier of Jet airways, i want to take connecting flight to Iceland via Amsterdam.
Now as Jet airways don't offer flight to Iceland, it will not be a single trip. Does this mean that i need to collect my luggage at Amsterdam?
If yes, then how can i avoid it and collect luggage directly at my destination.

EDIT:

I was planning to book 2 separate tickets as i didn't see Iceland as destination on Jet airways website. But based on the responses below it seems i can book single ticket across airlines with no codeshare.

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking of buying two separate tickets? One on Jet Airways from Delhi to Amsterdam and another ticket from Amsterdam to Iceland. Is that right? Or are you buying a single ticket with a connection in Amsterdam?

Comment: @ZachLipton: Jet Airways doesn't appear to sell tickets to Iceland at all (not even via codeshare), so I don't think one could do it with a single ticket.

Comment: @NateEldredge Jet Airways [interlines with plenty of airlines](https://www.jetairways.com/en/in/jetexperience/through-check-in-partners.aspx). It doesn't need to be a codeshare. I can get Orbitz to price me single tickets with Jet Airways connecting to Icelandair.

Comment: according to general rule of thumb, if the stay between the connecting flight is less then 12 hours luggage will be automatically transferred only if you are travelling with  Star Alliance airlines

Comment: Note that you will earn Jet Airways miles (if that's what you are concerned about) also if you buy at some other place which offers the trip on a single ticket.

Comment: If you buy a ticket from X to AMS and another ticket from Y to KEF, how is X supposed to guess that they shouldn't put it in baggage claim at AMS?  If you can persuade the person checking in the bags to do all the markings and data entry to make it happen...

But I doubt that they will agree to that.  In fact, if it isn't codeshare, I doubt they even know how.

If you assume it will happen and go there with two tickets, and it doesn't, what will you do then?

Comment: @WGroleau: Interlining and codeshares are two different things. It is completely routine to book a single itinerary with two different interlining airlines, no codesharing going on, and get baggage checked through from the original departure airport to the final destination.

Comment: Keywords "single itinerary."  I wrote of the reasons it is so difficult to get the airlines of _two_ separate tickets to coordinate baggage for you.

Answer (score 1):

From [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g188590-c170368/Amsterdam:The-Netherlands:Transferring.At.Amsterdam.Schiphol.html):

> If you are travelling Schengen to Schengen, or Non Schengen to Non
>   Schengen, there will be no immigration checks.  There are no security
>   checks at the gates.

And from [Schiphol Airport](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/page/smooth-transfers/):

> Most of the time, your baggage will be automatically sent to your
>   connecting flight. The only exception is if you’re travelling on two
>   separate tickets. In that case, your baggage will be delivered to
>   baggage reclaim area.

So it sounds like if you book your entire trip on one itinerary with Jet Airways, you won't need to collect your bags in Amsterdam when you connect.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Schiphol Airport in Amsterdam, but since Amsterdam will be his entry into the EU, he likely will have to collect his bags to clear customs and immigration, even if he is flying on to another EU airport.  Perhaps someone familiar with Schiphol Airport can elaborate.  (There are some exceptions to this, e.g. connecting to the US at some Canadian airports, bags are not collected by passengers during connections unless Customs and Immigration officers want to go through them.)

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Schengen airports don't require you to pick up and recheck luggage to clear immigration at the first port of entry on connecting flights, unlike the US. You go through immigration, but don't take the bags through customs until you arrive at your destination. However, here it sounds like the OP might be buying two separate tickets and so would need to recheck bags (and leave the secure area to do so), but we need to know more to know that.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie: Even more, the asker here is going to Iceland, which is not a member of the EU. He will need to import his baggage into the EU _only_ if he needs to recheck it in Amsterdam (because the check-in desks are inside the EU customs area).

Comment: @HenningMakholm : I read that Iceland Schengen visa is valid in all Schengen countries. So when you say Iceland is not member of EU, i hope that doesn't apply to Schengen Visa.

Comment: @Lokesh Iceland *is* a member of the Schengen area - the Schengen area is *not* an EU construct, it merely implements a specific freedom that the EU mandates, that of freedom of movement.  An Icelandic Schengen Visa is valid across the Schengen area, and is just as good as a French or German one.  https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/docs/schengen_brochure/schengen_brochure_dr3111126_en.pdf

Comment: @Lokesh: Correct, Iceland is a Schengen member -- but Schengen is about the movement of _persons_. The question (and Jim MacKenzie) was talking about _luggage_ handling for customs purposes, which is outside the scope of Schengen.